# SwiftUI - TabView with nested NavigationViews resets Navigationflow

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, tabview, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm having a TabView with Navigation Views in it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink("Link to my first Navigation Level", destination: MyFirstView())
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house")
                Text("Home")
                
            }.tag(0)
            
            NavigationView {
                Text("Second Nav Page")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                Text("Settings")
            }.tag(1)
            
        }
    }
}


struct MyFirstView: View {
    
    @State var selectedTag: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My First View")
            NavigationLink("(Working) Link to my second Navigation Level", destination: MySecondView())
            Text("But the Button in the Navigation Bar doesn't work")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("My First View", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading: HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: MySecondView(), tag: "xx", selection: $selectedTag ){
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Settings button pressed...")
                        self.selectedTag = "xx"
                    }) {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "gearshape.2.fill").imageScale(.large)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

struct MySecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("My Second View")
    }
}
```

Now I got a super weired behavior. If I click on "Link to my first Navigation Level" and then on "(Working) Link to my second Naviation Level" the journey works. If I click on "Back" while being in the second Navigation Level it goes back to the first Navigation Level.

Issue:

When I click on the gear symbol in the Navbar on the first Navigation Level it kind of escapes from the nested Navigation and sets it to the top level. This has the consequence that when I click on "Back" it brings me from the Second Navigation Level back to the very root screen but my expected behavior is that it should go back to the first Navigation Level.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Xcode 12.2 beta 3 and iOS 14.2 (not sure if it's a beta bug).

Many Thanks!

Comment: Don't use NavigationLink in navigation bar, see same in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59776373/12299030.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick (thanks @Asperi). Has to be outside tabBarItems

```
            NavigationLink(destination: AddDetailView(existingItem: nil), 
                isActive: $addMode) { EmptyView() }
```